# WebSocket connection failed on LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, websockets

I have a lwc that needs to connect to a WebSocket but I'm not being able to do it. It's always giving me the following error:

`WebSocket connection to "" failed`

I have my WebSocket url put into `Trusted URLs` and `Remote Site Settings`.

This is my LWC code:

```
connectedCallback(){
    this.wsSocket = new WebSocket("wss://websocketurl.com/ws/chat");
    this.wsSocket.addEventListener("open", () => {
        console.log('***connected to websocket');
    });
}
```

The problem is that I don't know how to pass the Authenticator header (which is Basic OAuth) and that's where I think the problem is

Is there a way to pass the `Authenticator Header`? And if not, what do I need to implement in order for this to work properly?

Regards,

Comment: This is hard to answer without knowing more about your websocket server implementation. I don't think websockets support setting headers like a normal http request. Can you share more about your websocket server?